# Is it possible to enable javascript in browser using server-side code?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Most of the pages of my website are called using Ajax. If someone disable javascript in his browser them Ajax functionality will not work. So is there any way of enabling javascript in browser using server-side code.(Or Any language like C#)?

Comment: I seriously hope not!

Comment: If you want people who don't have JS enabled in their browser to be able to view your website YOU should work around that.

Comment: use noscript tag and request user to enable javascript

Comment: No - enabling or diabling Javascript is a user action in the browser. The only thing you can do is use a `<noscript>` tag to inform the user that they should enable Javascript for your site

Comment: Duplicate of (now deleted) question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405398/turn-on-browsers-javascript/11405409#11405409

Comment: All you can do is detect if javascript is enabled or not and by using `<noscript>` tags, you can show special content when javascript is not  enabled.  Much of the web these days doesn't work at full function when javascript is disabled.

Comment: Direct the user to [www.enable-javascript.com](http://www.enable-javascript.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: @sshashank124 — It might be short and to the point, but it does answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

No. That would not be possible under normal conditions. If something like that gets invented, it would be a big security and privacy issue. Think of the TOR network. what will be the privacy left if JavaScript is enabled by the server ?

only thing you can do is detect if its enabled.

Comment: Is it bad habit to use Ajax functionality in Web-Development? Because it totally depends on user's browser settings.

Comment: No. AJAX is awesome. It totally depends on the place of implementation. If you need to give user data dynamically (without page refresh), then AJAX comes in handy. But don't use it unnecessarily. Here, read this for details: http://webdesign.about.com/od/ajax/a/aa092506.htm

Answer (score 1):

If someone choose to disable javascript, it is usually for security reasons. So you won't be able to enable it. (and that's a good thing)

But your question is a bit weird : "browser using server-side code" => browser use html code generated by server-side code. The browser can't see the server-side code.

What you can do is to display a message like "You must enable javascript to navigate on this website" (big red letters =) ) and you hide it on page load using javascript.

```
document.onload = function(){
    // correct it if i'm wrong, i'm used to jQuery
    document.getElementById('javascriptAlert').style.display = 'none';
    // or jQuery :
    $("#javascriptAlert").hide();
}
```

---

EDIT :

I forgot : the noscript tag can be use to ask the user to enable javascript.

Comment: Is it bad habit to use Ajax functionality in Web-Development? Because it totally depends on user's browser settings.

Comment: From my point of view, Ajax is really useful for a lot of things. You can load and dynamically adapt your page (you don't have to reload the entire webpage for a minor change). But for navigation it may become a bit useless (depends on your website). It is up to you, how do you think your website should work (think "design", and then think again :D). Good luck !